# Drupal 8 - different language for admin pages and frontend

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I have a Drupal 8 site set up with multiple languages.

I use a URL prefix with the language code to detect the current language, for example /es, /en, ... I set that up at /admin/config/regional/language/detection, and it's working fine.

The site has many languages, and the editors are not fluent in all of them. When they add a translation, the language of the backend changes. For example: adding or editing a Spanish translation changes the entire interface to Spanish. On the frontend, the links related to admin tasks (edit, delete, ...) also change to that language.

I'm aware that there 's an 'Account administration pages' detection method on /admin/config/regional/language/detection, and that there an 'Administration pages language' field on a user's account page when that method is enabled.

I tried messing around with this, but I have not succeeded in reaching the ideal scenario:

- Use language prefix to set the content language.
- Allow editors to use a language of their choosing on /admin pages, and ideally also for view/edit/... links on the frontend.

How do I configure /admin/config/regional/language/detection? What confuses me:

- Does the order of detections methods matter when I enable 'Account administration pages'?
- Do I need to enable 'Customize Content language detection to differ from Interface text language detection settings' on /admin/config/regional/language/detection? Will that allow me to have the frontend links in a different language than the content? If yes, how do I set that up?

Thanks